# Meteor. MongoDB upsert error: TypeError: keypath.split is not a function. (In 'keypath.split('.')', 'keypath.split' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

`Foo` is my `MongoDB` `collection`.
There I have only one `document`:

```
{
  0: {code: "basic", caption: "basic", points: 100},
  1: {code: "gold", caption: "gold", points: 200},
  2: {code: "platinum", caption: "platinum", points: 300},
  3: {code: "diamond", caption: "diamond", points: 400}, 
  id: "PnpbhFi8m7NqZXRr6"
}
```

When I am trying to `upsert` it I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: keypath.split is not a function. (In 'keypath.split('.')', 'keypath.split' is undefined)
```

This is my code:

```
const data = [
  {
    "code": "basic",
    "caption": "basic",
    "points": 100
  },
  {
    "code": "gold",
    "caption": "gold",
    "points": 200
  },
  {
    "code": "platinum",
    "caption": "platinum",
    "points": 300
  },
  {
    "code": "diamond",
    "caption": "diamond",
    "points": 400
  }
];

const doc = Foo.findOne();
Foo.upsert(doc._id, { $set: data });
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is your intent to have `data` be an array of object or a nested object with numbered keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$set` wrong. You have to pass object to `$set`:

```
Foo.update(doc._id, {
  $set: {
    4: data[0],
    5: data[1],
    6: data[2],
    7: data[3],
  }
});
```

Also you don't have to use `upsert`. From [meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert) about `upsert`:

> Modify one or more documents in the collection, or insert one if no matching documents were found

but your document exists, so there is no need for `upsert`, use `update`

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot